# Buck converter load specification

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCOA3C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know at the output side of the buck converter there is a resistor which makes a path to flow current as capacitor doesn't pass current.My questions are:

1. Besides this is there is any other purpose of this output resistor?
2. What does actually power rating mean in buck converter? How output resistor contribute in power rating?
3. Besides this resistor what kind of load is used in buck converters output port? Can inductive load be used in the output port?

Comment: Draw a schematic and show which resistor you are talking about. I can't think of any resistor in a buck converter design to which your questions would apply.

Comment: Buck converters require a minimum load to operate, so a resistor (minimum load) is connected to the output. It can also serve as a bleeder resistor(resistor used for discharging the capacitor while power is turned off).

Comment: @karthikJay I have seen plenty of buck converters which operate just fine with only the voltage feedback resistors (value above 10 kohm) connected. No minimum load required.

Comment: *I know at the ouput side of the buck converter there is a resistor which makes a path to flow current as capacitor doesnt pass current* Look at the datasheet of the LM2596 Buck converter. Note how in the Typical Application Schematic there's **no resistor** at the output. Sure there is a high value resistive feedback network in the chip but it has a high value, only very little current can flow through it.

Comment: @karthikJay: **Some** buck converters have a minimum load requirement (and some need a minimum load to be stable across all loads although no minimum load is stated in the datasheet).

Comment: @Arsenal I am talking about R1 resistor

Comment: karthik Jay i am tryting to build a buck converter whose output will be 12 volt,now what does power rating means of a converter?is it the rating dependent on load ?or output resistor?

Comment: FYI: The commutation diode is missing. Cathode between M1 and L1, anode to GND.

Comment: Power rating of a buck converter depends upon the inductor design, if it is designed for 1 amp, then the power rating would be 12W in your case.

Answer (score 1):

That resistor is almost certainly there to *represent* the actual load on the converter, for purpose of illustration, analysis, simulation or test. In a real application you would omit it.